# Security Issues on iPhone

Tags: iphone, security, authentication

I'm doing an app that needs to connect with a login form to the web. I'd like to store these informations, my questions are:

A) Is it safe to store these data into NSUserDefaults?

B) Should I use CoreData?

C) Is there safer method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CoreData is **not** secure unless you encrypt the data within it.

KeyChainAccess is apparently secure.  There is some useful code to access it here:

https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone

You just need the two files under the the security folder.

You can then use these helper calls:

```
+ (NSString *) getPasswordForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;
+ (BOOL) storeUsername: (NSString *) username andPassword: (NSString *) password forServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName updateExisting: (BOOL) updateExisting error: (NSError **) error;
+ (BOOL) deleteItemForUsername: (NSString *) username andServiceName: (NSString *) serviceName error: (NSError **) error;
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is not Safe for storing login details

Core Data is very ueful for persistent storage and also secure. Core Data Tutorial [Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/)

You can also use KeyChainAccess which is also secure.Sample code [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GenericKeychain/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007797-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)